# read from second character till first occurrence of separator

Tags: bash

This is how my variable name looks like: `p123456_19100210720_linux-86-64`

I am trying to get `123456` in a variable using variable expansion. I am able to get `p123456` using variable expansion and reading everything before first `_`.

```
patchname="p123456_19100210720_linux-86-64"
echo ${patchname%%*_}
```

This outputs `p123456`. Is there a way I can get only `123456`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the letters prior to removing everything after `_` if using `bash` is the preferred option

```
$ patchname="${patchname//[a-z]}"
$ echo "${patchname//_*/}"
123456
```

Using `sed` will be easier

```
$ sed 's/[a-z]\(.[^_]*\).*/\1/' <<< "$patchname"
123456
```

Comment: Don't use `$(echo something)`, the `$( )` and the `echo` basically cancel each other out (but create a useless subshell in the process). Just use `patchname="${patchname//[a-z]}"` (or maybe `patchname="${patchname#[a-z]}"` to make sure it's the first char that gets removed).

Answer (score 5):

It will be much easier using `BASH` regex operator:

```sh
[[ $patchname =~ [0-9]+ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"

123456
```

---

Alternative solution using `extglob`:

```sh
shopt -s extglob
echo "${patchname//+([^0-9]|_*)/}"

123456
```